# How to Remove( " )Character from String

Tags: php

I want to remove ( " )Character from String.
I tried str_replace,it work perfectly in some string and not working in below string,this shows error syntax error

```
$string = 'dfghhhhfgh 0201-228 8"X1" 'G' rgth fgh fgh';
echo str_replace('"','',$string);
```

I want  to remove ( " )Character from this type String, I also tried `preg_replace('/"/','',$string);`

`ltrim($string, '"');`

is there any other solution?,Thanks

Comment: If you plan to use single quotes to define your string you need to escape `'G'` like so `\'G\'`. Otherwise it's indeed a syntax error. Fix that and your code should work.

Answer (score 4):

Php shows you a syntax error in this string because

```
$string = 'dfghhhhfgh 0201-228 8"X1" >>'G' rgth fgh fgh';
```

You close you string in this moment >>

In your case you need to use quote escaping:

```
$string = 'dfghhhhfgh 0201-228 8"X1" \'G\' rgth fgh fgh';
```

In this case your example works correctly.

Comment: thanks for sharing, i have many string like this, is there any function for escaping bulkily

Comment: so you have to correct your strings first because this is a syntex error.